# SimpleJson Package Installation issue

Tags: python, installation, simplejson

I’m trying to use simplejson library  but i think something went wrong with my installation. it works with some functions for example i’ve tried it with simplejson.dumps and it works fine but when i try simplejson.loads i’m getting an error. I’m not sure if that’s the only thing there is a problem with but it’s the only one i’ve encountered. I’m testing with a simple script that looks like

```
import simplejson

json_data = {"name": "Jane", "age": 17}
data = simplejson.loads(json_data)

print(type(json_data))
print(type(data))

print(data)
```

this is the error im getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "dummy.py", line 4, in <module>

    data = simplejson.loads(json_data)

  File "C:\apps\python25\lib\site-packages\PIL\__init__.py", line 302, in loads



  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\simplejson\decoder.py", line 314, in decode

TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

i installed with py setup.py install.

```
Installed c:\apps\python25\lib\site-packages\simplejson-2.0.4-py2.5.egg

Processing dependencies for simplejson==2.0.4

Finished processing dependencies for simplejson==2.0.4

***************************************************************************

WARNING: The C extension could not be compiled, speedups are not enabled.

Plain-Python installation succeeded.

***************************************************************************
```

I’ve reinstalling it, but it hasn’t worked.

I am restricted to using this specific package and python 2.5.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be nothing wrong with your setup, the error is in your code.
SimpleJSON adheres the the same interface than the standard json module.

From the docs of [`simplejson.loads`](https://simplejson.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#simplejson.loads) :

> Deserialize s (a str or unicode instance containing a JSON document) to a Python object.

And your exception message is :

> TypeError: expected string or buffer

It is because you are giving an object, not the string representation of an object. You already have the result, no need to call the function.
A json library converts between text and object. Here, you already have an object (`json_data = {"name": "Jane", "age": 17}`).

In other words :

```py
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('{"name": "Jane", "age": 17}')  # loadString
{'name': 'Jane', 'age': 17}  # into an object (a dict)
>>> json.dumps({'name': 'Jane', 'age': 17})  # dumpString
'{"name": "Jane", "age": 17}'  # into a string (representing the object)
```